# How to return just distance from a google maps distance matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps-api-3

I want to determine the distance between two addresses using the google maps distance matrix API. How can I edit my code such that the output I get is only distance rather than the entire JSON dictionary?

I am currently using json which returns destination, origin, rows(`distance(text, value)` and `duration(text, value)`) and status. I can get it down to just displaying 'rows' but want to isolate `distance(value)`. `pick[i]` and `drop[i]` are inputs from a csv file.

```py
for i in range(1,10):
    source = pick[i]

    dest = drop[i]

    url ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?'

    r = requests.get(url + 'origins=' + source +
                       '&destinations=' + dest +
                       '&key=myapi') 

    x = r.json()

    print(i,x['rows'],"\n")
```

My current output is:

```
[{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '18.2 km', 'value': 18218}, 'duration': {'text': '21 mins', 'value': 1264}, 'status': 'OK'}]}]
```

Comment: I don't think that you can pass only fields you want to Google's API. However as suggested in documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#RequestParameters), you probably have to parse the returned json.

Comment: Reading the documentation usually answers that kind of questions. As you can see if you read it, there is **no option** to specify which fields are returned.

Comment: The API key you posted here is meant to be private. You might want to remove it.

Comment: @teivaz API keys are **not** private. Any website that uses the API exposes the key publicly (just look at the source code and you will see it). What you need to do though is to properly restrict your key as explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it. I just tested it and it works:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)
distance_result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origin, destination, units="metric")
print(distance_result["rows"][0]["elements"][0]['distance']['text'])
```

let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

This feature to specify only specific fields to be returned by the Google Maps Distance Matrix API is **not** currently available. You will need to parse the Distance Matrix API JSON response to get or display the value that you need. You should be able to access the data with something like this: `x["elements"][0]["duration"]["value"]`

In addition, if you are interested to have this feature, you can file this as feature request in Google's Public Issue Tracker:
https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#issue_tracker